# Include third part installation during ClickOnce installation

Tags: c#, clickonce

Is there possible to include a third party installer with an application published as a ClickOnce?
If so, how?

I have an application written in C# and the application is published as a ClickOnce application.

The application requires a USB-to-Ethernet adapter from D-Link. The USB-driver for the adapter is also required. Currently the USB-driver must be installed separably by the user.

Because it's mandatory to have the D-link USB-driver installed, I wonder if it could be packaged in the ClickOnce.
So when the ClickOnce is installed, then the D-Link's USB-driver for the adpater is also automatically installed.